# Listing out iterables from among builtins

Tags: python

I have the following code to list out all iterables among the builtins

```
b=dir(__builtins__)
print([x for x in b if '__iter__' in dir(x)])
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting an empty list

Comment: `import collections; [x for x in __builtins__.__dict__.values() if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you were trying to do:

```
print([x for x in dir(__builtins__) if '__iter__' in dir(getattr(__builtins__, x))])
```

Since `dir` just returns strings, you need to use `getattr` to get the actual object.

Answer (score 1):

`dir(__builtins__)` is a list of names. You're building a list of all the names in `__builtins__` that have an `__iter__` attribute, which is none of them, since `str` doesn't implement `__iter__`.

Comment: @sarathjoseph: The names are all strings. The name that `tuple` is associated with is the string `'tuple'`.

Comment: FWIW, in Python 3 `str` *does* implement `__iter__`.